# How to transfer a fraction of ERC20 Token?

Tags: erc-20

I have deployed an erc20 contract on ethereum testnet and want to transfer a fraction of erc20.

I used the transfer function to transfer tokens but I don't have any idea how can I transfer a fraction of a token using the transfer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERC-20 tokens actually do not have fractions, but internally use 256-bit words for accounting.

It is just convention that we set the decimal point on 10 exp 18 on this number, to communicate with humans.

So you can transfer a fraction of tokens by just calling `transfer()` with a number that is less than 10 exp 18.

Comment: I am using remix IDE and the transfer() doesn't accept value in decimal like "0.5" so how should I transfer in fraction?

Comment: Here is an answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.5*10%5E18

Comment: Pleae note that StackExchange breaks the link above, it should be a calculation